# How to Find All Switch Jump Tables in IDAPython

Tags: ida, idapython, ida-plugin, disassemblers, idapro-sdk

I'm using IDAPython on IDA 6.5 and I'm trying to get all the switch jump tables in a DLL. Mainly I'm interested in jump tables that are jumped indirectly:

```
jmp     ds:off_65018790[ecx*4] ; switch jump
```

Basically, what interests me is:

- The address from where the jmp happens
- The list of the possible locations, for example - loc_65018723, loc_65018736...

I already know how to get all the jmp addresses using IDAPython, but I don't know if it's a jmp to a jump table or just a normal jmp.

In most cases, IDA knows to identify those jump tables, so is there a way to get that info from the API?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have IDA 6.5 installed, but as far as I remember idaapi.get_switch_info_ex(ea) already was there. The simplest way to see reference usage of this function is searching python code with call to this function on github.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was exactly what I needed. If you post it as an answer, I will mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 2):

Decided to add a small code snippet to show how to iterate through the .text segment, obtaining all the switch table locations and storing the jump targets in a dictionary.

```
text_seg = idaapi.get_segm_by_name('.text')
jump_table = dict()

# iterate through all items within the segment
for head_ea in idautils.Heads(text_seg.startEA, text_seg.endEA):
    if idc.isCode(idc.GetFlags(head_ea)):
        switch_info = idaapi.get_switch_info_ex(head_ea)
        if (switch_info and switch_info.jumps != 0):
            loc = switch_info.jumps
            jump_table[loc] = list()
            element_num = switch_info.get_jtable_size()
            element_size = switch_info.get_jtable_element_size()
            for num in range(0, element_num):
                table_entry = loc+num*element_size
                jump_table[loc].append(idc.GetManyBytes(table_entry), element_size)
```

**Update**: To build upon this for newer versions of IDA

```
def find_jumps(si: ida_nalt.switch_info_t) -> list:
    jtable = []
    e_size = si.get_jtable_element_size()

    for num in range(0, si.get_jtable_size()):
        jtable.append(int.from_bytes(ida_bytes.get_bytes(si.jumps + (num * e_size), e_size), 'little') + si.elbase)

    return jtable

ea = 0x0000000000000000 # some ea
si = ida_nalt.switch_info_t()
if (ida_nalt.get_switch_info(si, ea) is not None): # jump table
    jtable = find_jumps(si)
```

This resolves the offsets to the with respect to `elbase` of the `switch_info_t` structure which IDA provides if `get_switch_info` is succesful. See: https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_nalt.html#ida_nalt.switch_info_t.elbase for more information, and cross reference this to the `c++` support if need-be at https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/sdkdoc/structswitch__info__t.html

Comment: `getnseg` receives a segment number, while `SegByName` returns a segment selector, these are not the same thing. Your first line is erroneous.

Comment: Additionally, using `idc.Dword` feels insecure and assumes the switch code is indeed structured the way OP described, which isn't always the case.

Comment: Thanks Nirlzr, the above snippet comes from my old script I used on ARM32 binaries to extract out jumptables in order to rewrite them. I've updated it to fix the mistakes you've pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

To safely get all references from a certain `EA`, there's `idc.XrefsFrom(ea, flags)`. You'll get an iterator for cross references from a certain `EA` (the switch-case's branch/jump instruction). switch-cases are easy to identify as they're always with more than two cross references targets.

According to [this](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_xref-module.html) the `flags` parameter is one of the following:

> XREF_USER = 32
>   XREF_TAIL = 64
>   XREF_BASE = 128
>   XREF_MASK = 31
>   XREF_PASTEND = 256
>   XREF_ALL = 0
>   XREF_FAR = 1
>   XREF_DATA = 2

The object you'll get from each iteration is an `ida_xref` object, exposing the following attributes:

1. `frm` - The source of the cross reference, the code that performs the jump in our case.
2. `to` - The target of the cross reference, the code that will be executed according to the jump table selector in our case.
3. `iscode` - Boolean, `True` if cross reference is a code cross reference, must be `True` in our case.
4. `type` - One of the available type values, see below. You could use `idautils.XrefTypeName(typecode)` to translate the integer you get here to a readable string.
5. `user` - Boolean, True if this cross reference was created by the user, opposed to being automatically created by IDA.

The valid cross reference types are, according to [this](https://github.com/idapython/src/blob/master/python/idautils.py#L119):

> ref_types = {
>    0  : 'Data_Unknown',
>    1  : 'Data_Offset',
>    2  : 'Data_Write',
>    3  : 'Data_Read',
>    4  : 'Data_Text',
>    5  : 'Data_Informational',
>    16 : 'Code_Far_Call',
>    17 : 'Code_Near_Call',
>    18 : 'Code_Far_Jump',
>    19 : 'Code_Near_Jump',
>    20 : 'Code_User',
>    21 : 'Ordinary_Flow'
>   }